# Android application approval process in playstore

Tags: android, google-play

i am new to android development i created one android application and i want to test this application in all aspects before submiting to the play store. I don't know the play-store approval process. please let me know the play-store approval process and also tell me how to test my application without any bugs(that will be rejected by play-store) and against to playstore approval process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much of approval process in play store, certainly not much like apple used to do.  You just need to make sure you read [this](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html) and your app is okay on all points.

> *tell me how to test my application without any bugs*

Well there is no short cut for that. Do your testing.. Google won't do it for you.. If your app is good, then only user downloads it.. It is not only Google that you have to consider..

Comment: This isn't true anymore. As of 2015, Google Play store apps are reviewed by humans, and are subject to similar approvals that iOS apps are: http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/17/app-submissions-on-google-play-now-reviewed-by-staff-will-include-age-based-ratings/

Answer (score 0):

There is no play store approval process.  They run some automated tests for malware and you'll be on the market in a few hours.  So just do enough testing that you feel happy with the quality.

Answer (score 0):

You're responsible for testing your own app. Google won't. There are just a few basic rules you need to follow, and your app will be approved:

1. You can't sell in-app content unless you use Google's in-app purchasing. You CAN sell physical goods using other payment methods.
2. You can't make your app free and then change them to paid later. Once they're free, they're always free.
3. You can't do anything racist, criminal, hateful, etc... and you can't do anything you don't disclose -- i.e. steal the user's contacts and upload them to your own server for malicious purposes.

Be very attentive to testing. If your app has bugs, users will quickly complain and down-rate your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "bug policy" for google play store. Even if your app contains bugs, google will still publish it. Develop your app keeping user in mind.